# To understand clearly extraintestinal diseases

Tags: microbiology, gastroenterology

Extradistestinal disease seems to prefer to "bowel" diseases, I think this is about diseases outside gastrointestinal tract so stomach.

Consider diseases ulcerative colitis and Crohn's disease (enteritis) as examples.
Colitis affects to colon, outside of small intestine, I think extraintestinal therefore.
Crohn's disease (enteritis) however affects to the small intestine so I would think intestinal disease (but this clause is wrong) - it should be at least have extraintestinal manifestations.

**What is the exact definition of the word *extra* in intestinal diseases?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain intestinal diseases have symptoms that appear concurrently in other systems of the body, but the bowel diseases *themselves* are not extraintestinal.

> Extraintestinal manifestations of inflammatory bowel disease are prevalent in both ulcerative colitis and Crohn's disease. The most common manifestations involve the musculoskeletal and dermatologic systems. Other manifestations involve the hepatopan-creatobiliary system (eg, primary sclerosing cholangitis) as well as the ocular, renal, and pulmonary systems<sup>1</sup>.

One of the key differences between extraintestinal manifestations and comorbid conditions (though seemingly not a necessity, the article cites primary sclerosing cholangitis as an counterexample) is that the extraintestinal effects will subside once the disease of the bowel is treated.

<sup>1</sup> Levine, J.S., Burakoff, R. (2011). Extraintestinal Manifestations of Inflammatory Bowel Disease. *Gastroenterol Hepatol (NY), 7*(4), 235–241.

Comment: Does there exist any extraintestinal disease with some type of diarrhea?

Comment: @Masi In that case, the manifestation wouldn't be extraintestinal, it would be directly related to the intestine.